# How to define BASE_URLs in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'd like to define  BASE_URLs for production and development as environment variables to be used in API calls like this:

```
DEV_BASE_URL="http://127.0.0.1:8080"
PROD_BASE_URL="https://example.com"
```

I have defined them in an `.env` file  then in my component I tried to import them like:

```
import {env} from '$env/dynamic/public'
console.log('DEV_BASE_URL is:', env.DEV_BASE_URL)
```

But I get `DEV_BASE_URL is: undefined` in the console.

The [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private) about different types of envs has just added to my confusions. The docs is awful.

So appreciate your help to resolve these global variables  in an idiomatic manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- first of all, let's change the `.env` content like follows

```
PUBLIC_DEV_BASE_URL="http://127.0.0.1:8080"
PUBLIC_PROD_BASE_URL="https://example.com"
```

- then in your `svelte` files import them like this

```js
import { PUBLIC_DEV_BASE_URL, PUBLIC_PROD_BASE_URL } from '$env/static/public'
```

- to load env vars based on the server mode, you should create a `.env` file for each mode, in this case `production | development` like follows

.env.development

```
PUBLIC_BASE_URL="http://127.0.0.1:8080"
```

.env.production

```
PUBLIC_BASE_URL="https://example.com"
```

- now you just import that variable and used

```js
import { PUBLIC_BASE_URL } from '$env/static/public'
```

for more information on how `Sveltekit` handles env vars check the documentation https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-public

for more information on how `Vite` handles env vars check this link https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes

Comment: Right, and then how to chose the relevant one based on being at dev or prod mode?

Comment: `Sveltekit` offer this `import { dev } from '$app/environment';` which is `true` if the dev server is running

Comment: I edited my answer, you can check it to see another solution offered by `Vite`